# Flex/Openlaslzo for RIAs?

Tags: apache-flex, openlaszlo

I recently stumbled upon flex/openlaszlo (OL). Both seem very useful and I have a few questions about them:

> 1. What is needed to deploy flex apps? From what I understand, the flex sdk
>      is open source, but the other tools
>      (for development and deployment) are
>      proprietary.
> 2. What is needed to deploy openlaszlo? Is it completely open
>      source (from development to
>      deployment), or does it have
>      development/deployment "gotchas" like
>      flex?
> 3. Specifically, I'd like to use flex or openlaszlo to either augment or
>      replace an editable table I created
>      using js, ajax, html, and css. Is this
>      the type of thing flex/OL can/should
>      be used for? Are there any drawbacks
>      or pitfalls to using flex/OL for this
>      rather than straight js, ajax, html,
>      css?

Thanks.

**Edit:** Are there any licensing (use) restrictions on applications built on flex? i.e. applications built on flex can be for only non-commercial use, unless a commercial license is purchased?

Answer (score 2):

The following link has some discussion about openlaszlo and flex, it may help you:
[Use the best open source client-side framework for cloud computing](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-cloud-clientsidefwk/index.html?S_TACT=105AGX01&S_CMP=HP)

Answer (score 1):

1. You do not need anything special to deploy Flex apps.  Just put the compile app (a SWF file) on any web server.  Flex apps can talk to any back-end.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Do you know of any licensing restrictions? i.e. applications built on flex can be for only non-commercial use unless a a commercial license is purchased?

Comment: There is a EULA for using the Flex SDK but you can certainly do whatever you want with the output from the SDK (the compiled SWF).  The output is yours for however you want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Flex SDK is free, but Flex Builder is not. You can use the free and open source [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/) to write flex apps - it doesn't have drag-n-drop features like flex builder, but it offers code hinting and stuff. I don't know about openlaszlo.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer your last question: the biggest drawback to using Flex is that it requires the client to have the Flash Player plugin installed in their browser. Not that big a deal for most people since Flash Player is over 98% of all computers. With the straight Javascript, AJAX, HTML, CSS approach it should work on all browsers, assuming you wrote it correctly.

Comment: And assuming JavaScript is turned on.  Some stats indicate that about 2% of users have JavaScript turned off.

Comment: Good point, James. So any way you slice it, you can at most target ~98% of all users.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the link providing details of tools/IDEs for developing OpenLazlo applications 
http://wiki.openlaszlo.org/Development_Tools

Answer (score 1):

Re: "What is needed to deploy openlaszlo? Is it completely open source (from development to deployment)"

OpenLaszlo is OpenSource, but the typical versions you install come with the main components pre-compiled into a SWF for the SWF run-time. However, you can download the full source code if you wish to look at it and/or compile the core yourself:

Last official released version (4.9.0): http://download.openlaszlo.org/4.9.0/openlaszlo-4.9.0-src.tar.gz

Nightly builds:

http://download.openlaszlo.org/nightly/trunk/ (you will see "source" as an option after you click the link of the version you want)

OpenLaszlo does not require anything else to be deployed but itself, except if your application is compiled to the SWF run-time then the user will need the Adobe Flash player installed in their browser to use it.