# Openlaszlo in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, openlaszlo

Can anybody tell me how to add the openlaszlo plugin to the eclipse or any IDE for openlaszlo ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

IDE4Laszlo - http://wiki.openlaszlo.org/IDE4Laszlo -  an Eclipse-based development environment for creating, editing, debugging, and testing applications based on the LZX declarative mark-up language.

Also check https://stackoverflow.com/a/11676129/363075 for details of other development tools for OpenLaszlo.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [Spket IDE plugin](http://www.spket.com/laszlo.html). It has some support for Laszlo, and I've used it in projects. The old IBM IDE project has been discontinued back in 2006. The Eclipse Update Site for Spket is http://www.agpad.com/update.

If you would rather use an XML Schema file with Eclipse, there is an Ant build script capable of generating a custom XSD file for your application. See the [OpenLaszlo Schema Generator](https://www.ohloh.net/p/OpenLaszlo-SchemaGenerator) site for more info.